# What is jmap's default heapdump format?

Tags: java, jmap

We are taking heapdumps and have a question:

`jmap -dump:file=heapdump.hprof,format=b`

- If you specify `format=a` it will be usage message in ascii
- If you specify `format=b` it will be binary

OK great, but what if you don't specify a format at all?

`jmap -dump:file=heapdump.hprof`

Which one will it pick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default is binary data file (hprof). You can just try running the command without specifying the format and with `format=b` and you will find out yourself that they have the same format.

```
alessio$ file heapdump.hprof 
heapdump.hprof: data
```

Comment: gotcha. thanks!! i did the same thing but figured i'd share it in a sof post